# Add button outlets to IBoutletCollection Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I want to add 15 `UIButtons` to a `IBOutletCollection` and change the label of each `UIButton` separately. Can I assign a **tag** to each button and then somehow change the button label relating to the tag of the button? Or do they need to be individual outlets for me to change the individual button label?

Comment: yes you can do this with help of button tag

Comment: ok cool, how would i add to the individual button label?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in button click method. set **tag** and check condition for that and set 
**title** for particular **tag**

```
-(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender{

UIButton * btn = (UIButton *)sender;
int btag = btn.tag;

if(btag == 1)
    [btn setTitle:@"Your Title " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else if (btag == 2)
     [btn setTitle:@"Your Title " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fish the buttons according to their tags out of the IBOutletCollection Array in a for loop

```
UIButton *theButton;
for (theButton in yourIBOutletCollectionArray){

    if (theButton.tag == /* Your Tag Number OF Choice */) {
    [theButton setTitle:(NSString *) forState:(UIControlState)];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Avoid 0 as tag value, because 0 is default tag value for all controls.
```

Set all buttons with unique tags. Make one IBAction method and connect it to all your buttons in IB. And Use `switch` like this (let tags are 3,4,5...)-

```
   -(IBAction) btnClick:(id)sender
    {
       UIButton * btn = (UIButton *)sender;
       switch([btn tag])
       {
          case 3:
             [btn setTitle:@"First_Button_Title " forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
             break; 
          case 4:
            // change btn title 
             break; 
          case 5:
            // change btn title 
             break; 
          default:
              break;
   }
```